# C# Global Class - Add from a method and Read from another

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

How do I make the DoScrape method below add to the external CompanyInfo variable and then at the loop of button1_Click access that list to write to a text file?

```
namespace Test1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public class LocationNameAndLink
    {
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

LocationNameAndLink CompanyInfo = new List<LocationNameAndLink>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Parallel.ForEach(Brands, item =>
        {
            string initialSiteName = "http://www.site1.com/" + Brands;
            DoScrape(initialSiteName);
        });


        StreamWriter sw03 = new StreamWriter("websiteCompanyDetails.txt");
        foreach (var item in CompanyInfo)
        {
            sw03.WriteLine("\"" +  item.Name + "\",\"" + item.Link + "\""    );
        }
}

public static void DoScrape(string PageLink)
{
    string SiteLink;
    string SiteName;
    SourceCode = WorkerClass.getSourceCode(nextPageLink);
    SiteLink = SourceCode.Substring(0, 50);
    SiteName = SourceCode.Substring(51, 50);
     CompanyInfo.Add(new LocationNameAndLink 
                     {
                         Name = SiteName,
                         Link = SiteLink 
                     });
                 }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `DoScrape` an *instance* method, rather than a *static* method.

A static method isn't specific to any particular instance of the type, so it has no implicit `this` reference - whereas your `CompanyInfo` field is an instance variable - each instance of `Form1` has a separate variable.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) for more information on the meaning of `static` - it's an important concept to understand.

Comment: resharper strikes again?

Comment: @paul - what has resharper to do with this?

Comment: Sorry had to hide the original code but DoScrape is a recursive method. Does that change the answer?

Comment: @SaidurRahman: No, not at all. But don't just fix it without understanding it - make sure you *really, really* know what `static` means.

Comment: @AppDeveloper it is perhaps over-zealous when suggesting that methods should be made static

Comment: @paul - yes, resharper does that, but a good develop knows when to make a static method!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, given a CompanyInfo how do I make DoScrape add to this "list" and button_click loop through the list ?

Comment: @SaidurRahman: What do you mean by "given a CompanyInfo"? Both methods are using the variable within the `Form1` instance. If that's confusing for you, I strongly suggest you take a step back and go over some introductory C# tutorials.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know the semantics of it but I hope you understand what I am trying to do here

Comment: @SaidurRahman: I'm saying you *must* know the semantics. It's *vital* that you do so. It's pointless trying to write any more "real" code until you understand the difference between `static` and instance members, and how variables work in general. Forget everything else until you understand that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand your point but I am trying to solve this problem here. I couldn't do it on my own and looking for solution or hints (the purpose of this site) how do you expect me to learn, if you repeat to me what I know and only being condescending ?

Comment: @SaidurRahman I would take any advice Jon has to say with a huge smile on my face. He's not being condescending; he has given you the answer `make DoScrape an instance method, not a static method`, and has also given you a resource to understand HOW to do just that.

Comment: @SaidurRahman: If you "solve" this problem without really understanding it, you'll run into another problem 5 minutes later. If you take the time to understand the problem fully now, it will save you a lot of time in the long run. I've already given you the solution and a link to learn more; I'm not sure what you mean about repeating to you what you know - which bit of what I've said did you already know?